# How to make sliding picture/frame?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make something like - (See under "Applications You May Like")

http://www.facebook.com/apps/directory.php

When you click on right button - you get a sliding appearance of applications moving. How do you do it ? Any reference ?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous solutions out there which you can use.  I've recently implmented [jcarsouellite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/), which can be found [here](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/).  Minimal effort to integrate.  Excellent library.  If this isn't exactly what you want, take a look at the source code and start editing.

Answer (score 0):

Like Marcc said, there are tons of these sliding plugins for jQuery out there.

I like [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding) and [Anything Slider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/).